# Очищение textinput после вызова alert

Tags: javascript, react-native

Есть компонента

```
export default function AppTextInput({icon, placeholder,onChangeText, ...otherProps}) {

const  onChanged =(text) =>{
    let newText = '';
    let numbers = '0123456789';
    for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text=='0') {
            alert("zero is not allowd");
        } else if (numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1) {
            newText = newText + text[i];
            onChangeText(text)
        } else {
            alert("please enter integer numbers only");
            
        }
    }

}
return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
        {icon &&
            <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{marginRight: 10}} name={icon} color={colors.grayMedium} size={20}/>}
        <TextInput style={defaultStyles.text} placeholder={placeholder}
                   onChangeText={onChanged}  maxLength={3} {...otherProps}
        />
    </View>
    )
}
```

Хочу сделать так чтоб после вывода alert, поле textinputa полностью очищалось , пробовал text=' ', но не помогает, подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Comment: Из этого куска кода, похоже, что надо сделать вот так `onChangeText('')`

Comment: Работает, спасибо!